# Accessing Blade layout templates in subfolders Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I want to put Blade layout templates in subfolders.

I can't work out how to include them using the Laravel 8 component format

Blade template file structure:

```
/views
    /layouts
        /app.blade.php
        /registers
            /general.blade.php
```

```
// test.blade.php
<x-app-layout></x-app-layout>  // works

// test2.blade.php
<x-registers.general-layout>   

      // Unable to locate a class or view for component [registers.general-layout].
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `render` method in your component class, and make it points for your blade file in the subfolder :

#### old

```
 /**
 * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View|\Closure|string
 */
public function render()
{
    return view('layouts.general');
}
```

#### new

```
 /**
 * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View|\Closure|string
 */
public function render()
{
    return view('layouts.registers.general');
}
```